Doubt about simplification step when solving ODE $t \frac{dy}{dt} = y + \sqrt{t^2 + y^2}$
I have a doubt regarding a simplification step when solving the ODE:
$$t \frac{dy}{dt} = y + \sqrt{t^2 + y^2}$$
Apparently it's an homogeneous ODE, so we can perform the substitution $y = t v$. And we get:
$$t \left(t \frac{dv}{dt} + v \right) = t v + \sqrt{t^2 (1 + v^2)}$$
Wolfram alpha simplifies this expression as:
$$t \left(t \frac{dv}{dt} + v \right) = t \left( v + \sqrt{1 + v^2} \right)$$
I get how to solve it from there, but that step is not clear to me. Shouldn't we have $\sqrt{t^2 (1 + v^2)} = |t| \sqrt{1 + v^2}$? Can it be assumed from the problem that $t \geq 0$?

By default, Wolfram Alpha works in the complex domain. This includes that the root symbol is not, as commonly used, a real-valued scalar function, but a generalized set-valued function that includes all the possible complex roots.
In that sense, the transformation is correct, as all the possible sign variations remain preserved under this step. But if you want to translate the calculation into a more usual real-valued context, you have to resolve the set-valued map into all the variants for a real-valued map.

Or to be more precise, as a CAS is a computer program doing algebra as one central pillar, the first root symbol stands for an algebraic variable solving $r_1^2=t^2(1+v^2)$, which is then factorized to $r_1=tr_2$ where $r_2^2=1+v^2$. Thus no algebraic information is lost and expressions containing the same roots can be combined without creating spurious solutions.
